# Rate of which a virus spreads is modelled by a differential equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The rate of change of the number of infected people within a population can be modelled by the following equation:

$$\frac{dN}{dt}=0.0001*N(80000-N)$$
Calculate how many get infected after two weeks?

Note that $t=0$, $N=1$
Units are in days.

Is it possible to calculate the number infected with partial fractions or differentiate (Newton's law of cooling) to solve for value $N$ when $t=14$?

How is this done?

Comment: You can solve this equation using the logistic function.
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#In_ecology:_modeling_population_growth

Comment: This is Bernoulli type ODE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $N = 0$ and $N=80000$ are constant solutions to the differential equation.

Now we exclude constant solutions and rewrite

$$\frac{dN}{N(80000-N)}=0.0001dt$$
$$\frac{1}{80000}[\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{80000-N}]dN=0.0001dt$$

Integrating both sides results in:

$$\frac{1}{80000}[\ln{N}-\ln{(80000-N)}]=0.0001t+\frac{\ln{c}}{80000}$$

Remember the constant of integration is arbitrary, I used $\frac{\ln{c}}{80000}$ as constant to get an easier result. Now combine the logarithms using $\ln{a}-\ln{b}=\ln{\frac{a}{b}}$ and multiply with $80000$.

$$\ln{\frac{N}{80000-N}}=8t+\ln{c}$$

Now we introduce the exponential function on both sides to get

$$\frac{N}{80000-N}=e^{8t+\ln{c}}=ce^{8t}$$

Now we solve this for $N$ to get the general solution to the differential equation.

$$N=80000\frac{ce^{8t}}{1+ce^{8t}}$$

Using the initial condition $N(t=0)=1$ for the previous equation, we can find $c=\frac{1}{79999}$. Now, we are able write down the solution to the initial value problem (IVP).

$$N=80000\frac{e^{8t}}{79999+e^{8t}}$$

Now plug in $t=14$ to get the answer to your problem.

Comment: would you be able to show the full process towards the answer, since I used partial fractions to achieve the result and would like to see this alternative method. thanks for the help!!!

Comment: I edited my answer.